# Bokeh is not serving file regularly

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to host the following example using bokeh serve

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py

I'm running the following command.

`bokeh serve sliders.py`

For some reason, when I visit `my_url.com:5006/sliders`, nothing is displayed. The server readout doesn't even register a `GET` or `404` error. It just loads indefinitely.

Curiously enough, when I visit
`my_url.com:5006`
A get request is logged by the server with a `302` status(redirect). The new page it's redirecting to is never rendered.

Edit: The bokeh serve command is called on another computer on our local network.

Comment: Can you first verify that you do NOT have tornado 4.5 installed? It was released after the last Bokeh relelase, but was incompatible and broke things. There will be a new Bokeh release in a few weeks that is compatible with the new Tornado version.

Comment: @bigreddot that solved my issue by downgrading tornado to 4.4--perhaps consider writing it in an answer.

Comment: This worked. Thank you @bigraddot and FTA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado 4.5, which was released *after* Bokeh 0.12.5, introduced a breaking incompatibility. If using Bokeh 0.12.5 or earlier, you **must** make sure you are using Tornado<4.5. The next Bokeh release 0.12.6 will work correctly with Tornado 4.5 when it is available in early June 2017.